# Difference between datetimes in Hours, Mins, Seconds

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I am trying to get the difference between two datetimes and display it in string  as hh:mm

```
q.parambyname('vstart').asdatetime:=  vstart;
q.parambyname('vend').asdatetime:= vend;
d:= vend-vstart;
mins:= d * 1440;
q.ParamByName('mins').asBCD:= mins;
```

currently the database stores it in minutes

example (0.39)

I would like to then take it from database and display it in the string format hh:mm

Comment: Do you really need `mins` field in your Database? `vstart`  and `vend` fields already contain all information you need to return difference between them as query result (in format you need).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In `DateUtils` there is a function `MinutesBetween` which can be used as such:

```
m := MinutesBetween(vend,vstart);
yourHMStr := Format('%2.2d:%2.2d',[m div 60,m mod 60]);
```

Comment: This answer gives hh:mm but What about seconds as it mention in the Title?

Comment: @Dreamer64, use [System.DateUtils.SecondsBetween](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.SecondsBetween) . `s := SecondsBetween(vend,vstart); HMSstr := Format('%2.2d:%2.2d:%2.2d',[s div 3600,(s div 60) mod 60,s mod 60]);`, where s is an `Int64` variable.

Answer (score 5):

I can propose this simple code using `DateUtils`:

```
DiffTimeStr:= FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss', TimeEnd - TimeStart);
```